# Spring 4 framework compilation error

Tags: java, spring, maven, compiler-errors

I'm going to compile spring-core sources and add all dependencies but I got this error:
DefaultNamingPolicy is not resolved in the `SpringNamingPolicy` class. I've not found required jars. What have I missed?

```
 public class SpringNamingPolicy extends DefaultNamingPolicy{
 .
 .
 .
 }
```

maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jopt-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>jopt-simple</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How were going to compile them? Are you using Maven?

Comment: @chrylis yes, I added all dependencies

Comment: `spring-core` already has its own POM. Are you saying you wrote your own?

Comment: @chrylis there is no `pom.xml` in the zip file I downloaded from spring.io

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution for that problem is really simple. You just need to run root build [image] and wait for it to finish.